# Redis streams is returning an empty array

Tags: redis

I created a new Redis steam using the following command.

```
XGROUP CREATE A mygroup $ MKSTREAM
```

I added the below mentioned data

```
xadd A * X 1
xadd A * X 2
xadd A * X 3
xadd A * X 4
```

I am reading the data using the following command.

```
XREADGROUP GROUP mygroup Alice COUNT 1 STREAMS A 0
```

Its returning an empty array

```
1) 1) "A"
   2) (empty array)
```

I am using Redis version 6.2.1. Kindly help me to debug the error.

Comment: Right Redis cli command XREADGROUP GROUP mygroup Alice COUNT 1 STREAMS A >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use XREADGROUP command to read message, you should specify `>` as ID, instead of `0`.

Reference from the [doc](https://redis.io/commands/xreadgroup#differences-between-xread-and-xreadgroup):

> - The special > ID, which means that the consumer want to receive only messages that were never delivered to any other consumer. It just means, give me new messages.
> - Any other ID, that is, 0 or any other valid ID or incomplete ID (just the millisecond time part), will have the effect of returning entries that are pending for the consumer sending the command with IDs greater than the one provided. So basically if the ID is not >, then the command will just let the client access its pending entries: messages delivered to it, but not yet acknowledged. Note that in this case, both BLOCK and NOACK are ignored.

If ID is not `>`, you can only read pending messages, however, in your case, there's no pending message, since you have not consume anything.